# Html table with custom css to only effect one table

Tags: html, css

I have a project with multiple tables. I am trying to get this example to work with one of the tables without effecting all the other tables in the project. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNBLGo

I tried adding a class name to the css. However, it does effect all the tables in the project. Which I don't want, and I only want it to effect the table who I am using the class name.

**CSS**

```
.mytable {
width: 100%;
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0;
border: 2px solid black;
}

.mytable thead, tbody, tr, td, th { display: block; }

.mytable tr:after {
content: ' ';
display: block;
visibility: hidden;
clear: both;
}

.mytable thead th {
height: 30px;
line-height: 30px;
/*text-align: left;*/
}

.mytable tbody {
height: 100px;
overflow-y: auto;
}

.mytable thead {
/* fallback */
width: 97%;
/* minus scroll bar width */
width: calc(100% - 17px);
}

.mytable tbody { border-top: 2px solid black; }

.mytable tbody td, thead th {
width: 19.2%;
float: left;
border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.mytable tbody td:last-child, thead th:last-child {
border-right: none;
}
```

I am referring to the table like

```
<table class="mytable">
```

How can i fix this css in that it doesnt effect all the tables in the project, and just the one specifying the css class name?

Thank you

Comment: Your example doesn't have the classnames, and only has 1 table. So it's not very helpful.

Comment: There is only one table in the codepen, can you show an example of the behaviour that you want?

Answer (score 2):

Your code should already mostly do what you want, however note that where you define multiple elements to style, e.g.

```
.mytable thead, tbody, tr, td, th { display: block; }
.mytable tbody td, thead th {
```

You have to repeat the use of the .mytable class name, otherwise you start targeting all tbody, tr, td, etc. e.g. the above examples should be namespaced like this:

```
.mytable thead, .mytable tbody, .mytable tr, .mytable td, .mytable th { display: block; }
.mytable tbody td, .mytable thead th {
```

You will have to go through and repeat this everywhere where you have styles you want to apply just to this table split with a comma.

Comment: Beat me to it by like 30 seconds!